# Are we must handle exception? when get data

Tags: c++, exception

I guess, when i get some int data and I do not handle exception
and if input value is greater than int max value, it happen overflow

So in that case, we must handle these exceptions.
Is it right? But many code do not do.
I'm really worder...

```
int num = 0;       // edited in c++
std::cin >> num;   // input value == 2147483647
                   // it greater than INT_MAX
```

Comment: If you want your program to be able to gracefully handle that input, you need to put in code to handle it. Some people don't care what happens if your input value is 2147483647--they work in a domain where they know it's never going to happen, or "something unspecified goes wrong" is an acceptable outcome, or what have you.

Comment: Thank you. But how to ensure that their domain never happen exception. Eventually they must handle exception in domain. Is not it?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example: If you know the input value is always going to be calendar years because that's what you're feeding your program, you don't necessarily need to handle the "but what about three billion?" case. The kind of input your application will need to be able to handle depends on the application.

Comment: If you want `cin >> num` to report errors to you, you should configure it via its [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method to throw an [`std::ios_base::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) exception on failure.